# How to implement mutual authentication for client in Openssl?

Tags: ssl, openssl, mutual-authentication

What function calls do I need to do for mutual authentication ? I have searched a lot, but didn't find anything useful.

Can anybody help me doing this ?

Comment: Which flavor of mutual authentication are you trying to use? TLS-SRP? TLS-PSK? TLS  with PKIX certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function calls you are looking for are the [`SSL_set_verify()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) family.  On the server side, specifying `SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT` requires a valid client certificate.  On the client side, just `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` is needed.

Both sides must also ensure that anonymous ciphers are not allowed in their specified cipher list (set with [`SL_CTX_set_cipher_list()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html)).

Comment: I have used this, when i am trying to write it is returning -1.
Can u tell me where I can be wrong ?

Comment: @bharat: Not from that little information.  Dump the actual errors with `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);` (and call `SSL_load_error_strings()` at program startup to make sure you have the error strings available).